# What's the best way to open the last displayed fragment upon reopening the app?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am using drawerlayout to allow the user to open different questionnaires. The questions in the questionnaire are different fragments. The problem is that when a questionnaire is started and say the use goes to question no. 5 and exits the app then she or he will have to start from the home page ie first fragment in the drawer layout. How do I save the last fragment ie question shown so that I can show it again when the app is reopened?

Below is the code in one of the fragments that do not open up if the user taps the Home button.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { \\ handle view related code and triggering other functions }

@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        cardContext = context;
        if (context instanceof OnShoppingDoneListener) {
            onShoppingDoneListener = (OnShoppingDoneListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bundle = getArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        onShoppingDoneListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("cartContent", selectionItemArrayList);
    }
```

And here is the relevant code Main Activity where I open that particular fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnRestaurantSelect {

    public void onRestaurantSelect(Bundle bundle){

        boolean direction = bundle.getBoolean("direction");
        if (direction) {
            MenuCardFragment fragment = new MenuCardFragment();
            openFragment(bundle, fragment, true);
        } else {
            AddressFragment fragment = new AddressFragment();
            openFragment(bundle, fragment, false);
        }
    }

    private void openFragment(Bundle bundle, Fragment fragment, Boolean direction) {
        // Passing the pickup or delivery option + address + schedule + restaurant + order details + payment
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        //Starting fragment with animation
        if (direction) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you now that for a particular question, that it belongs to a certain fragment>> for instance Q.3 goes for Fragment-B how do you know that it's for fragment-B not C?

Comment: That's because it's coded based on certain parameters e.g. which stream of question the user selects. If you look at the onRestaurantSelect function, you'll notice that I open the bundle and see if the user wants to proceed to the next question or to the previous one. I have similar functions determined by the interface that determine the next or previous question.

Comment: So, what I mean that if your question database has a field that indicates which fragment each should be handled through; then you can just save the last question id; and based on this id; go to its related fragment when the app relaunches

Comment: Got it. Yes, I can save that in the bundle but then how would I handle that onResume? It would be in the main activity, am I right? I am not sure how to go about implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Design a key for each fragment, when the app exits, save that key in a SharedPreference, than when the app restart, get that SharedP and open that fragment